# Jquery: Expand Div Upwards

Tags: jquery

Alright, I have a div which is 50px (height), and the width does not matter that has a title displayed. I want to use jquery, so when I hover over the div it expands upwards to (70px) to reveal the content hidden below the title

```
<div id="box">
<h1>Title Goes Here</h1>
<p>this is the hidden text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In HTML, content normally flows downwards. Are you sure you want an div to expend *upward*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This snippet should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
    $("#box").hover(function() {
        $("#box").animate({'height': '70px', 'top': "-20px"});
    }, function() {
        $("#box").animate({'height': '50px', 'top': "0px"});
    });
});
```

Here's a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MeBxJ/

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#box").hover(function(){
    $("#box").css('height','70px');
}, function(){
    $("#box").css('height','50px');
});
```

EDIT: I just understood how you want to expand only upwards. I have just a solution for this, if your design permits this: use position:absolute and a bottom:x value. The box will expand upward

Comment: Stop posting solutions without formatting them correctly or any explanation whatsoever. Also, the solution's syntax is obviously wrong, and even if it works, it's not answering the OP's questions - he want's slide, ie. animation, and also *upward* - this given no context would simply slide downwards

Comment: 1) I tried to format corectly, that's why I edited my post. 2) I just seen that he wants it to be upwards so I came to put a comment for this: if your design permits using a position:absolute and a bottom:x should do the trick

Comment: @cripox You shouldn't use the `code` tag here - `code` is for inline code in HTML - you're looking for `pre`, and anyway Stack Overflow uses Markdown, which is cleaner than HTML - have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Yi the syntax was wrong first and the formatting was not correct, but I edited my answer in a couple of minutes: formated and corrected the syntax. I just hit the add button quickly to see if I can be the first answer (i answered 3 posts and while I was writing there were many other answers) - so this was kind of an experiment. Sorry, I didn't thought you will be checking it so quick.

Comment: @cripox - Being the first to post isn't very useful if it's not a valid answer :)  Post a *useful* answer quickly and that's great, but if it's not even formatted (which you can do in one button click) that's just a lack of effort IMO.

Comment: @nick Yes, you are right, I just told that it was an experiment, and also I was going to edit it right away.

Comment: @Cripox, thanks for your input
@Ender, thanks! Helped a lot. I should have thought of adding the "-20" to it..

Comment: @Louis Stephens - my pleasure