# Tailwind On hover slide out footer div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add an on-hover event to my card objects. I want on hover to extend the card to show the footer div. It works almost correctly right now, but the content in the `card-footer` is slightly visible. I can fix this by adding top padding, but the effect is still not correct. The effect is more of an *uncover* type instead of the desired *slide out*, I have tried different setups like;

- extending the padding.
- using a combination of hidden and visible

What I figure it comes down to is the `card-footer`
is not *sliding* behind the `card-body` div. Im not entirely sure what to try next.

Config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      transitionProperty: {
        width: 'width',
        height: 'height',
        spacing: 'margin, padding',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Code

```
    <div class="relative flex h-screen flex-col justify-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-50 py-6 sm:py-12">
      <div id="main-feed" class="flex h-full w-full px-2">
        <div id="card-holder" class="flex h-full w-full flex-wrap justify-start gap-2 overflow-y-auto bg-slate-200">
          <div id="card1" class="z-1 group relative mb-2 h-48 w-fit overflow-y-clip rounded-lg bg-slate-500 p-2 pb-2 transition-all duration-500 hover:h-64">
            <div id="card-body" class="relative z-10 mb-auto h-44 flex-col self-start bg-stone-600">
              <div class="flex w-full justify-between gap-2">
                <div>Content 1</div>
                <div>Content 2</div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex w-full">
                <div>Title</div>
              </div>
              <div class="flex w-full justify-between gap-2">
                <div>Content 3</div>
                <div>Content 4</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="card-footer" class="z-5 relative mb-auto w-full items-center gap-2 self-end truncate pb-5">
              <div class="flex w-full flex-row justify-between">
                <div>Content 3</div>
                <div>Content 4</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[Tailwind Play Link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zDeK7DpmOy)

Here is a [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663456/jquery-expand-div-upwards) question, but the entire content moves upward instead of just extending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to like this:

```
 <div class="relative flex h-screen flex-col justify-center overflow-hidden bg-gray-50 py-6 sm:py-12">
    <div id="main-feed" class="flex h-full w-full px-2">
      <div
        id="card-holder"
        class="flex h-full w-full flex-wrap justify-start gap-2 
        overflow-y-auto bg-slate-200"
      >
        <div
          id="card1"
          class="z-1 group relative mb-2 h-48 w-fit overflow-y-clip rounded-lg bg-slate-500 
          p-2 pb-2"
        >
          <div class="relative z-10 mb-auto h-44 flex-col self-start group-hover:h-28  bg-stone-600">
            <div class="flex w-full justify-between gap-2">
              <div>Content 1</div>
              <div>Content 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex w-full">
              <div>Title</div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex w-full justify-between gap-2">
              <div>Content 3</div>
              <div>Content 4</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="z-5 relative w-full items-center gap-2"
          >
            <div class="flex w-full my-5 flex-row justify-between">
              <div>Content 3</div>
              <div>Content 4</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You added `group` in `card-1` but missed adding `group-hover` in the `card-footer` div.

Comment: You said about `card-footer` in your question,  but no updation in your working code. Please update your 'working code example'.

Comment: Here's the live demo link: https://zvuoz0-3000.csb.app/

Comment: Thank You! Its not exactly what I was looking for, but you gave me a solid foundation for the card that I was able to tweak and get it working nicely. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah! I am so glad that I could help to give you an idea. Yesterday, I found this code pen maybe, I am not sure if you are looking for this, but it might be helpful to you.  link: https://codepen.io/harrycresswell/pen/aVLowG

Comment: You're a legend! it did!